# Cheap metal discs?

Tags: metal

I am in need of cheap metal discs >30 mm diameter, about 1-2mm in height - like a big coin.

This is because I want to weigh down the bases for my tabletop miniatures.

So far I have been using coins, but the ones available in my country are far from perfect :)

Any ideas what could I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume a hole in the middle doesn't matter.

Penny washers (also called mudguard washers, fender washers, or repair washers) are thick enough (often 1.2mm)  and made of steel.  The smaller sizes are usually 25mm diameter, but M8 and M10 are certainly available in 40 and 50 mm diameter.

You can get them in hardware shops, but there's more choice on ebay, at least where I am.

Comment: I recall reading years ago of a fellow who desired to purchase nickel (US) sized washers. The local store charged $0.12 each. He returned home and drilled holes in nickels!

Comment: @fred_dot_u here in the UK our lowest value coins (including the largest at 26mm diameter) used to be "copper" (actually bronze), but now they're plated steel and a pain to drill.  They do however cost about 1/10 of a penny washer when bought in bags of 10 - but a bag of 100 costs little more than a bag of 10

Answer (score 1):

Lead, probably free, cut it with scissors to any size, about 50% more dense than steel, copper and nickel. In the US plumbing stacks ( roof penetration vents) normally are covered with sheet lead ( Measured at 0.039" , basically 1 mm- unusual for a US product.), when new shingles are put on , I pick up a couple of the old lead liners / flashing. I think any supplier of roofing materials would have sheet lead flashing available. Only down side is lead has had bad public relations and is politically incorrect . But no one will know if you do not tell them it is lead. I find it very handy for low strength custom straps, etc.

Comment: Nice idea, especially since lead is VERY heavy - although i would advise to cover it for things you touch with your hands! Lead IS toxic over prolonged exposure. Alas, i can accept only one answer, but you still have my thumbs up!

Comment: If you don't dissolve it in acids like nitric and acidic  is is no problem . I have used lead weights on aquarium plant for 60 years- no problem. It was the best  material for drinking water pipes for 2000  years . Because of this the plumbing trade and plumbers were named after lead  ; plumbum  in Latin , atomic symbol Pb.